# Merge these two regular expressions into one

Tags: php, regex

I feel like I can learn a lot by seeing these two regular expressions as one. Mainly selecting the space in between `>` and `<` while not selecting the `>` and `<` themselves, so I can replace it with "" rather than "><". Is there a way that these could be merged without selecting that space?

```
    $html = preg_replace('/(\n)|(\r)/',"",$html);
    $html = preg_replace('/>(\s+)</',"><",$html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+|(?<=>)\s+(?=<)/',"",$html);
```